# Where is the data recorded in JsonStore?

Tags: database, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I downloaded from [Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html), JSONStore [example](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip)

Project has been successfully loaded into the browser and on a real device, but I can not understand where the input data is stored, what file?

Eclipse + IBM Worklight + JSONStore.

Answer (score 1):

- Android:`/data/data/com.[app-name]/databases/wljsonstore`([source](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_support.html))
- iOS Simulator: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/[id]/Documents/wljsonstore` ([source](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_support.html))
- Browser: [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)