# Does the JSONStore data/documents from Worklight persist on device (iPhone/Android) even after deleting the App?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I was wondering when using IBM Worklight to build and deploy apps on devices, would the JSONStore persist or be removed when deleting the app from the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data you store inside a JSONStore collection when using Android or iOS will be removed when the application is uninstalled. You can actually confirm this, the files that JSONStore uses to persist data are shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428207/186909).

Answer (score 1):

Application private data is removed from the device along with the app when you uninstall.